# How to reduce time to find the n-th place from consecutive digits number for less than 1 second

Tags: php, algorithm, digits

I'm following the programming test, and there are questions like this

> From this consecutive digits:
>
> **123456789101112131415161718192021....**
>
> For example The 10th digit is 1 The 11th digit is 0 and so on
>
> - What is the 1,000,000th digit?
> - What is the 1,000,000,000th digit?
> - What is the 1,000,000,000,000th digit?
>
> **Your solution should run below 1 second.**

I've been made an answer but still more than 1 second. I try to use polynominal.

***So, how I can reduce the time to find n-th place from digits above?***

This is my answer, (PHP):

```
function digit_pol ($n) {

  $counter = 1;
  $digit_arr = array();

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {

    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($i); $j++) {

      // If array more than 100, always shift (limit array length to 11)
      if($i > 10) {
        array_shift($digit_arr);
      }

      // Fill array
      $digit_arr[$counter] = substr($i, $j, 1);

      // Found
      if($counter == $n) {
        return $digit_arr[$counter];
      }

      $counter++;
    }

  }

}

/**
 * TESTING
 */

$find_place = 1000000;

$result = digit_pol($find_place);

echo "Digit of " . $find_place . "th is <b>" . $result . "</b>";
```

Comment: How many digits will there be between 0 and 9 (inclusive)? How many digits will there be between 10 and 99 (inclusive)? How many between 100 and 999?

Comment: I'm not good in English by the way. But I hope I can explain goal clearly.
@aioobe, do you mean "how to use my code?" It's completely the code that I have been test. You can test it, just copy and save it. It's still more than 1 second for 1,000,000th number.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I'd try to eliminate using strings and calculate it based on mathematics. I'd try to calculate the number x that is printed at or around the searched place. In a first loop I'd increment n and calculate how many numbers there are between 10^n and 10^(n+1) and how long the string for all those numbers would be. That way I would be approaching quite fast. In a second loop it would be necessary to find the rest of the number. Finally you know that the searched digit is at position x in number y, which is quite easy to calculate.

Comment: @ajiyakin, you misunderstood me. I'm not very familiar with PHP, but if I produce an answer in pseudo code or Java, would this still be helpful to you?

Comment: @aioobe, I'm sorry. OK, I get it... Yes, ofcourse.

Comment: @kebs, how I can reduce time to find n-place from digits above. so I can find for 1,000,000th place under 1 second.

Comment: No, not in comments, but by editing your question. The questions are supposed to be fully understandable for future readers, without requiring to read the comments. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for next time.

Comment: I've change the title and including the question there... thanks @kebs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's important to realize is that it's easy to take big steps:

```
1 digit numbers: 123456789           -   9 * 1 digit
2 digit numbers: 101112...9899       -  90 * 2 digits
3 digit numbers: 100101102...998999  - 900 * 3 digits
4 digit numbers: ...
```

Now you can do a recursive solution that skips over 9×10<sup>*k*</sup>×*k* digits at a time, until you reach the base case where `n` is in the range of digits in the current magnitude.

When you know which particular range to look in, it's fairly easy to find the `n`th digit. First divide `n` by the length of each number. That turns the *digit offset* into the *number offset*. Now add 10<sup>*k*</sup> to that to get the actual number to look in. At that point it's a matter of finding a specific digit in a given number.

Take for example `n = 1234`:

- `n > 9`, so it's not in the single digit range:

  - Skip over the single digit range (i.e. `n -= 9`) and continue on 2 digit numbers...
- `n > 90 * 2` so it's not in the two digit range either

  - Skip over the 2-digit range (i.e. `n -= 90*2`) and continue on 3 digit numbers...
- Now `n < 900 * 3` so we're looking for a digit in the `100101102...` sequence
- Since each number in this sequence is 3 digits long, we can find which particular number to look in by doing `100 + n / 3`. In this case this equals `448`.
- We now simply compute `n % 3` (which equals `1` in this case) to find which digit to pick. The end result is thus `4`.

Here's a solution in Java:

```
public static char nthDigit(int n, int digitsInFirstNum) {
    int magnitude = (int) Math.pow(10, digitsInFirstNum - 1);
    int digitsInMagnitude = 9 * magnitude * digitsInFirstNum;

    if (n < digitsInMagnitude) {
        int number = magnitude + n / digitsInFirstNum;
        int digitPos = n % digitsInFirstNum;
        return String.valueOf(number).charAt(digitPos);
    }

    return nthDigit(n - digitsInMagnitude, digitsInFirstNum + 1);
}

public static char nthDigit(int n) {
    return nthDigit(n, 1);
}
```

Comment: I think your solution is correct, but why do you use a recursion instead of a simple loop?

Comment: That's just the way I thought about the problem. It could just as well have been implemented as a loop.